# running a script from within crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an application that creates a report using crystal reports.  The data for the report is created in db tables that are built on the fly and then deleted after the report has been created.  I would like to save the database that create the report.
I have access to the reports, so I was wondering if it is possible to embed a script in the crystal report that would run when the report is created and move the data to another location, such as via a batch script.

Can anyone tell me if this can or cannot be done?  Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Can you edit your 'controller' application? That would be the best place to do it.

Comment: no - there is no opportunity to modify the program that creates the report.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In the .rpt, go to **Database Export** and **Add Command** as shown below.

I don't know what the proper SQL syntax is (the query in the sample image threw an error), but once you work it out, you could probably do it this way.  This [example](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_erq/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333233313335333133303330%7D.do) from Business Objects uses this command as part of a larger question.

(However, since the original DB is immediately deleted, you'll have to specify a new database to put the table in.  I don't know if that's possible.)

[image: Sample Image of what i'm talking about]

Comment: yeah - I don't think that will work being that the db is deleted.  I will look into it, though.  Thanks.